# 3D effect at bottom of container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, containers

I want to create a 3D-like effect in my container. I dunno how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvbwY.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That isn't anything 3D. It can easily be achieved by using the `boxShadow` property of `decoration` of the `Container` widget.

You can then play around with things like `color`, `blurRadius` to get the desired effect.

Sample code:

```
class Shadow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Shadow')),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
                  offset: Offset(0, 25),
                  blurRadius: 3,
                  spreadRadius: -10)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like charm. Sorry, I can't upvote because my reputation is below 15. I have marked it as solved.

Comment: Oh that's completely fine. Glad to have helped :) I upvoted your ealier question to increase it.

Comment: Cool, All the best for your Flutter journey.